# javascript sort of integers fails

Tags: javascript

There must be something very simple wrong with this code, but it doesn't sort.  Why is that?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            var topArray = [];
            topArray.push(1000);
            topArray.push(298);
            topArray.push(2000);
         topArray.sort();
            alert(topArray[0] + "," + topArray[1] + ", " + topArray[2]);
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add sorting options to it, as noted in here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var topArray = [];
        topArray.push(1000);
        topArray.push(298);
        topArray.push(2000);
     topArray.sort((function(a, b){return a-b}));
        alert(topArray[0] + "," + topArray[1] + ", " + topArray[2]);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the numbers by numbers, not by string, which is the default sorting.

> [**Description**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)
>
> If `compareFunction` is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order.

```
topArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In default [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts based on string comparison instead,  implement custom sort function.

```
topArray.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });
```

---

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) :

> If ***compareFunction*** is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For example, "Banana" comes before "cherry". ***In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in Unicode order***.